# Strategies to map attributes from multiple dimension tables

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to tackle a requirement in AAS (Azure Analysis Service) tabular model.

In the underlying data model (specific to a particular application), I've a Sales Fact table which joins with multiple dimension tables (lets call these application specific dimension tables) using usual PK-FK relationships.

- These application specific dimension are frozen for any changes in
  DWH, at the end of reporting month-year and hence can be considered
  to have snapshots for all reporting month-years.
- Each of these dimension tables has a corresponding "enterprise"
  version which is a Type 2 dimension table. That is, for a dimension
  such as Product, the enterprise version of the stores the history of
  changes for dimension attributes with usual fields such as valid-from
  date (start of the month-year), valid to-date (end of the month date)
  and latest indicator ('Y' value for the latest version of a specific
  reporting month-year) . An new attribute value means a new Product
  FK.

Both versions of these dimension tables and the Sales fact would be part of the AAS tabular model.

Now, as part of the reporting requirement I need to build a report (over this tabular model) running for a particular reporting month-year and show Sales data along with specific dimension attribute for the month-year.
Additionally, the report needs to show the data of these dimension attributes from the "enterprise version" of the dimension tables as well, with the latest values (Latest indicator='Y').

For example

Considering just one set of dimension tables

Product-App (Product Name, Product Group, Product PK .... so on)
Product-Enterpise (Product Name, Product Group, Valid-From, Valid-To, Latest Indicator ... so on)

and the Sales Fact :-

**if the user is running the report for Nov-2021 and running this in Jan-2022, the report needs to show Nov Sales data with

1. Product attributes from Product-App and
2. Latest values of the Product attributes from Product-Enterprise
   That is; for point 2 requirement, the tabular model needs to provide a way for the user to bring the latest values of the Product dimension attributes from Product-Enterprise.**

My understanding is: such capability would mean that to bring the latest values of specific dimension attribute in this scenario/data model, a calculated column or measure approach would need to be taken. Either a calculated column: to map and get the latest values of dim attributes in application-specific dimension or a measure. These calculated columns and measure would then can be consumed from the model for reporting.

I'm looking to any pointers if this is the best approach or are there any alternate approaches can be taken to best address such a requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use the type-2 SCD with the fact table joined to row that was valid at the time of the sale, which is the normal use of an SCD. Or if you only want the latest values, simply filter for `Latest indicator='Y'` in the query that loads the tabular model.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the response. There are two versions of the dimension tables: Application version and enterprise version. Both are type-2. So when I run the report for Nov month, the sales rows have a skey for Nov month and bring Nov Product data from application dim (its a snapshot table and doesn't change after month end). The end users also need to see latest data (Latest Ind=Y) from the enterprise dim however it join would be on the same skey value hence it won't being the latest data for an attribute. The only approach I could figure here is to go for calculated column in AAS model.

Comment: So just filter the Enterprise dim for current=Y in the loading query.